# exporting data from cloud foundry via python

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I am looking for the steps to export data from `Cloud Foundry` cloud via Python program using `cf` client.

I have gone through https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client 
but there is no information on data export. Can anyone please provide guidance on the steps?

Comment: What do you mean with "data"? Apps, binds, routes, domains, logs, ...?

Comment: Yes, there's no one single "download everything" option. You need to go through make the API calls to download what is important to you. Probably start with the "app" and work out from there, so get your app name, env variables, bound service info, mapped routes & of course app bits. Keep in mind that your service data is outside CF, so if you want to download data from the service you'd have to make separate calls to the service itself or a backup option through your service provider. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JanGaraj  i need to get the logs i.e. request and response of micro services.

Comment: @DanielMikusa thank you! i will work on the steps as mentioned by you.

Comment: What is a problem? Readme already contains info how to get logs: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client#application-logs